# Cache issue when creating shared memory between kernel space and user space

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel, dma

I am writing a kernel module on NVIDIA's Jetson AGX Xavier (ARM architecture). I am creating a shared memory between kernel space and user space in the following way:

1. Allocate memory in kernel space using `kzalloc()`.
2. Use `dma_map_single()` to get bus address for the allocated memory.
3. Use `remap_pfn_range()` to map the memory to user space.
4. In user space, use `mmap()` to get a pointer to this shared memory.
5. Write data to the shared memory via `memcpy()`.
6. Read the shared memory in kernel space to see if it contains the data that was written from user space.

I am facing an issue that when I read the memory from kernel space, it sometimes contains up-to-date data, and sometimes it does not contain up-to-date data, which makes me suspect a cache related issue. I have used `pgprot_noncached()` in the kernel module to make the memory non-cached, but still facing this issue. The relevant portion of the kernel module code is shown below.

```c
static int tx1_mem_get(struct file* file_ptr, struct vm_area_struct* mem_struct)
{
    int ret_val;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long start_addr;
    unsigned long page_frame_num;
    unsigned long mem_size;
    struct device* device_ptr;

    if (tx1_mem_count < BUFFER_COUNT) {
        /* Obtain the device pointer for the device which is requesting the memory */
        device_ptr = &pcidev_global_ptr->dev;

        /* Get the array index to store the addresses */
        i = tx1_mem_count;

        /* Allocate TX1 Buffer */
        tx1_data_buffers[i] = kzalloc(BUFFER_SIZE, GFP_DMA | GFP_ATOMIC);
        if (tx1_data_buffers[i] == NULL) {
            sprintf(msg_buffer, "WARNING: failed to allocate tx1 buffer %d", i);
            umtrx_ep_msg(msg_buffer);
            return 0;
        }

        /* Get the TX1 DMA address */
        tx1_dma_buffers[i] = dma_map_single(device_ptr, tx1_data_buffers[i], BUFFER_SIZE, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);
        if (tx1_dma_buffers[i] == DMA_MAPPING_ERROR) {
            sprintf(msg_buffer, "WARNING: failed to obtain dma memory for tx1 buffer %d", i);
            umtrx_ep_msg(msg_buffer);
            kfree(tx1_data_buffers[i]);
            tx1_data_buffers[i] = NULL;
            return 0;
        }

        /* Set memory attribute flags (VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP = VM_RESERVED; VM_RESERVED flag not supported in new kernel versions)*/
        mem_struct->vm_flags |= VM_READ | VM_WRITE | VM_SHARED | VM_LOCKED | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP;

        /* Set the page to non-cached */
        mem_struct->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(mem_struct->vm_page_prot);

        /* Obtain required parameters for creating a mapping */
        start_addr = mem_struct->vm_start;
        page_frame_num = virt_to_phys(tx1_data_buffers[i]) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
        mem_size = mem_struct->vm_end - mem_struct->vm_start;
        if (mem_size > BUFFER_SIZE) {
            sprintf(msg_buffer, "WARNING: couldn't map tx1 buffer %d, can't map more than %d bytes", i, BUFFER_SIZE);
            umtrx_ep_msg(msg_buffer);
            dma_unmap_single(device_ptr, tx1_dma_buffers[i], BUFFER_SIZE, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);
            tx1_dma_buffers[i] = 0;
            kfree(tx1_data_buffers[i]);
            tx1_data_buffers[i] = NULL;
            return 0;
        }

        ret_val = remap_pfn_range(mem_struct, start_addr, page_frame_num, mem_size, mem_struct->vm_page_prot);
        if (ret_val != 0) {
            sprintf(msg_buffer, "WARNING: couldn't map tx1 buffer %d", i);
            umtrx_ep_msg(msg_buffer);
            dma_unmap_single(device_ptr, tx1_dma_buffers[i], BUFFER_SIZE, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);
            tx1_dma_buffers[i] = 0;
            kfree(tx1_data_buffers[i]);
            tx1_data_buffers[i] = NULL;
            return 0;
        }

        /* Reserve the obtained memory, so that it is not swapped out by the kernel. Kernel space and user space can both access this buffer, so it must be
         * reserved. */
        reserve_mem_buffer(tx1_data_buffers[i], (unsigned int)(BUFFER_SIZE));

        /* Memory has been obtained, and reserved. Now populate it with the physical address using GPC-DMA */
        write_phys_addr(tx1_data_buffers[i]);

        sprintf(msg_buffer, "tx1 buffer %d acquired", i);
        umtrx_ep_msg(msg_buffer);

        tx1_mem_count = tx1_mem_count + 1;
    } else {
        umtrx_ep_msg("WARNING: failed to acquire tx1 buffer. tx1 memory is full");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to use `dma_mmap_attrs()` API instead of `remap_pfn_range()` (as per my understanding, `dma_mmap_attrs()` creates a mapping to user space without the need for a physical address or page frame number). However, this makes no difference.

Currently SMMU is enabled (it is enabled by default on NVIDIA AGX Xavier). If I disable SMMU and use the following user space code to explicitly flush cache, then the issue is resolved.

```c
void flush_cache(void* start, size_t size)
{
    // Ensure start address is aligned to cache line size
    uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)start & ~(uintptr_t)(CACHE_LINE_SIZE - 1);

    // Calculate the end address alligned to cache line size
    uintptr_t end = ((uintptr_t)start + size + CACHE_LINE_SIZE - 1) & ~(uintptr_t)(CACHE_LINE_SIZE - 1);

    // Flush the cache for each cache line in the specified range
    for (; addr < end; addr+= CACHE_LINE_SIZE) {
        __asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0" : : "r"(addr));
    }

    // Ensure completion of cache maintenance operations
    __asm__ __volatile("dsb sy");
}
```

However, I can't disable SMMU due to some other limitation in my application. As per my understanding, the method I have used to create a shared memory should give me an uncached memory. What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something obvious here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The size of the shared memory is 4MB, but I have tried going all the way down to 4KB but still no luck (4KB is the page size, and the smallest size which the kernel allocates successfully using `kzalloc()`).

Comment: dma_map_single is used to map memory for a single non-shared use. dma_alloc_coherent may be used to get non-cached, shared memory. Locking and memory barriers may also be used to assure proper visibility of data.

Comment: Each time data is updated (by any of the actor), you need to synchronize caches by calling DMA streaming APIs.

Comment: @0andriy, I have tried using DMA streaming APIs ( dma_sync_single_for_cpu() and dma_sync_single_for_device() ), but the problem still persists.

Comment: @stark, dma_alloc_coherent() is also giving same results as dma_map_single(). Problem still exists even if dma_alloc_coherent() is used.